# Code to Draw simple PushButton in Quartz?

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I know that, Cocoa uses quartz underneath to render the UI.
Thus can anybody share source code underneath that generates this PushButton displayed on screen?

I need this as a part of my research where I am trying to figure out if its possible to have all the UI elements on Mac using quartz (Of-course all 2D elements). I have been able to render others elements but Buttons and its variants still blocks me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HIThemeDrawButton`, documented in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Headers/HITheme.h`.

Comment: You mean it uses carbon framework to draw buttons stuff on screen? I am confused. I mean, if you look at this [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/MacOSXOverview/MacOSXOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001067-CH205-BCICAIFJ), in Figure 1-1  Layers of Mac OS X, it clearly says quartz is below carbon layer. So carbon should make use of quartz. Right?

Comment: I analysed your answer and it turns out Carbon makes use of Quartz under the layer. But my question was about Cocoa. Do you have any idea how things goes with Cocoa?